# iOS (12.1) google shows "title" in address bar, how?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, url

Using HTML, JS, or anything that can be loaded into the iOS browser, Im trying to find a way to modifiy the URL bar to show something other than the URL (title, text, anything).

From what I have read (its been asked on here a lot) and elsewhere it appears this is **not** possible.

I accepted this for a while until now as I have just seen on my iphone running 12.1 that a google search changes the URL bar to the searched term, even when you click in the URL bar, it just shows the searched term?

So what magic are they doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think it is to do with google, it is to do with the iOS default search engine integration.

To change your search engine:

*Settings* -> *Safari* -> *Search Engine*

Shown in the picture below:

[image: search Engine]

When I select bing as my search engine the same thing happens:

[image: bing]

When I change to google:

[image: Google]

So it is iOS integration